# converting data in dataframe to a list under special conditions in pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas

the following is a subset of a data frame.
I want to create 4 lists:

```
list 1: list of all WD1 as follows:
[flu-like symptoms, dizziness, major mood swings, lots of anxiety, tiredness,  Dizziness, headaches, neck pain, headache, nausea] 
list 2: comment_id: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 14, 14, 17, 17]
list 3 drug_id [lex.1, lex.1,  lex.1, lex.1, lex.1,  lex14, lex14, lex14, lex18, lex18]
```

As you see,  if value in WD columns is not NAN, I capture the comment_id  and drug_id for that value.

[image]

I know that I can iterate the rows to capture each WD using the following code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows()
```

but I do not know how to say `if it is not NAN`
and also, when I am adding the captured value to a list I already defined, the list does not return a list. Data in the list are in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `rowid` which corresponds to the column index within each combination of `comment_id` and `drug_id` by a `cumcount()`, and then unstack it with the two id columns as index:

```
df1 = (df.assign(rowid = df.groupby(["comment_id", "drug_id"]).cumcount() + 1)
       .set_index(["comment_id", "drug_id", "rowid"])
       .rename_axis(("comment_id", "drug_id","")).unstack(level=2))

# rename columns from multi-index to single index
df1.columns = [''.join(map(str, col)) for col in df1.columns]
df1.reset_index()
```

[image]

---

*Data Setup*:

```
WDs = ["flu-like symptoms", "dizziness", "major mood swings", "lots of anxiety", "tiredness",  "Dizziness", "headaches", "neck pain", "headache", "nausea"] 
comment_id = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 14, 14, 17, 17]
drug_id = ["lex.1", "lex.1",  "lex.1", "lex.1", "lex.1",  "lex14", "lex14", "lex14", "lex18", "lex18"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"WD": WDs, "comment_id": comment_id, "drug_id": drug_id})
```

---

*Update*:

Looks like you want the reverse, given the data frame `df1`, you can firstly transform it to long format and then each column will be the one you need, you can just use `tolist()` to convert them:

```
df2 = df1.set_index(["comment_id", "drug_id"]).stack().rename("WD").reset_index()   
comment_id, drug_id, WD = df2.comment_id.tolist(), df2.drug_id.tolist(), df2.WD.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please let me know how to print WDs, comment_id, and drug_id ?

Comment: print(WDs)? Do you mean these lists are in text file?

Comment: No. I do not know how you created such a output.

Comment: I updated with a different method. I misinterpret your question firstly. I thought you have those lists and you want to create the data frame. In the update, `df1` will be your data frame. `stack()` and extracting the columns should give you those lists.

Comment: I highly appreciate your time.